# How we call place_order api in stripe?

Tags: stripe

How do we call **place_order** API in stripe and what are all the parameters needed.

Comment: Can you describe your requirement in details.

Comment: Hi Dhiren Vasoya , I am using stripe payment API for placing orders, initially, I called stripe.createPaymentMethod() in order to get the payment_id, but after getting payment_id,  I need to call /V1/stripe/payments/place_order API, for that what are the parameters, that I need to pass for the place_order API.I am using stripe in Magento-2-PWA

Comment: I placed the Stripe form in magento-2-pwa and get the payment_id by using stripe.createPaymentMethod(), after that, I need to call /V1/stripe/payments/place_order api in-order to get the order sccess but I am not sure, How I will call that API and what are the parameters, that need for that API.

Answer (score 2):

The  `/V1/stripe/payments/place_order`

Used for place order on stripe

It uses two properties as arguments in its place_order method like below

```
{
  "result": "string",
  "location": "string"
}
```

Where the `location = cart` &

```
result =
    array (
      'paymentMethod' =>
      array (
        'id' => 'pm_1JBJV4DsrXo4utioMuovb41V',
        'object' => 'payment_method',
        'billing_details' =>
        array (
          'address' =>
          array (
            'city' => 'Musselburgh',
            'country' => 'GB',
            'line1' => '72 Albert Place Musselburgh',
            'line2' => 'Scotland',
            'postal_code' => 'EH21 8LE',
            'state' => '',
          ),
          'email' => 'any@any.com',
          'name' => 'any any',
          'phone' => NULL,
        ),
        'card' =>
        array (
          'brand' => 'visa',
          'checks' =>
          array (
            'address_line1_check' => NULL,
            'address_postal_code_check' => NULL,
            'cvc_check' => NULL,
          ),
          'country' => 'US',
          'exp_month' => 12,
          'exp_year' => 2024,
          'funding' => 'credit',
          'generated_from' => NULL,
          'last4' => '1111',
          'networks' =>
          array (
            'available' =>
            array (
              0 => 'visa',
            ),
            'preferred' => NULL,
          ),
          'three_d_secure_usage' =>
          array (
            'supported' => true,
          ),
          'wallet' => NULL,
        ),
        'created' => 1625836334,
        'customer' => NULL,
        'livemode' => false,
        'type' => 'card',
      ),
      'shippingAddress' =>
      array (
        'recipient' => 'any any',
        'organization' => '',
        'addressLine' =>
        array (
          0 => '781 APPLE PARK WAY',
        ),
        'city' => 'CUPERTINO',
        'country' => 'US',
        'region' => 'CA',
        'postalCode' => '95014-0642',
        'phone' => '2433423',
      ),
      'payerEmail' => 'any@any.com',
      'shippingOption' =>
      array (
        'id' => 'matrixrate_matrixrate_1725',
      ),
      'cart' => 'qEZSTuB6HBwOwsLoHCTpoiMTLQHD0zD1',
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, you saved my day. I will back if its work fine

Comment: The API is running, and it returns 200, but I have received an empty response, is there anything wrong.

Comment: You need to check further in code may be it should return order id , also did you check if order placed or not.

Comment: Can you please mention what is ['shippingOption']['id']

Comment: may be shipping method code

Comment: Thanks for the response

Comment: In place_order API , we have this line  **$quote = $this->cart->getQuote();** and for me , this quote return empty , its because of why , do you have any idea. But by using cartId , I can able to view the cart details via API

Answer (score 0):

To call the Stripe place_order API, you can use the official Stripe PHP library or any other Stripe API library that supports the place_order method. Here's an example of how to call the place_order API using the official Stripe PHP library:

```
// Set up Stripe API keys and instantiate Stripe client
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('your_stripe_secret_key');
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('your_stripe_secret_key');

// Create a payment intent and specify the payment amount and currency
$paymentIntent = $stripe->paymentIntents->create([
  'amount' => 2000, // 20.00 USD
]);

// Get the client secret and publishable key for the payment intent
$clientSecret = $paymentIntent->client_secret;
$publishableKey = 'your_stripe_publishable_key';

// Return the client secret and publishable key to the client-side JavaScript
echo json_encode(['client_secret' => $clientSecret, 'publishable_key' => $publishableKey]);
```

The above code creates a payment intent using the paymentIntents method of the Stripe API client, and specifies the payment amount and currency. The client_secret is then retrieved from the payment intent object, and returned to the client-side JavaScript along with the publishable_key.

Here are the parameters needed for the paymentIntents->create() method:

- amount: The amount of the payment in the smallest currency unit (e.g. cents for USD).
- currency: The currency of the payment (e.g. "usd" for US dollars).
  payment_method_types: An array of payment method types accepted by the payment intent (e.g. ['card', 'alipay']).
- payment_method: The ID of an existing payment method (e.g. a card or digital wallet) to attach to the payment intent.
- customer: The ID of an existing customer to associate with the payment intent.
  metadata: Optional metadata to include with the payment intent (e.g. order ID, customer ID, etc.).
- statement_descriptor: A custom statement descriptor to include on the customer's payment statement.
- receipt_email: The email address to send a payment receipt to.
  You can find more information on the Stripe payment intent API and its parameters in the Stripe API documentation.